# Get new file id after transferOwnership=true and moveToNewOwnersRoot=true

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to move a file from one user in our domain to another. I am accomplishing this by creating a new Permission and setting `transferOwnership` and `moveToNewOwnersRoot` to true. It works fine.

But after I move the file to the new owner's root, I want to move it into a nested folder. I can do that with a PATCH to the `/drive/v3/files/fileId` endpoint, but I need to know what the file id is. When the create permission call moved the file, the file get's a new id, but I can't see a way to get it. The create permission call returns a permission, not the associated file. Is there a way to get the file id from a permission id?

Comment: Can i see your code, I would love to test your use case.    Are you saying when you move the file that the file id changes?   Doesnt permissions move return the new file object?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DalmTo, you are correct that the file id does not change just because you transfer ownership. Makes sense. It works now that I'm not making a false assumption, but it's so slow. I'm making 4 API calls just to copy a file into another user's drive in a mirrored folder structure.

1. Copy the file on the origin user's drive
2. Share the copied file with the destination user in order to prevent an email notification being automatically sent out to the origin user during the ownership transfer (an email notification is still sent to the destination user, but that's ok).
3. Transfer the copied file to the destination user's root.
4. Set the parent of the copied file to the folder id that mirrors the origin user's parent folder.

Wish there was a way to combine some of these calls, and I may need to do more to check for existing share permissions, for example. And this is for every file. I don't understand why this use case isn't better supported by the Drive API.